# Story or movie where an AI tries to reassure a user, but gets stuck repeating the same line over and over

Tags: story-identification

I read this in the last few years, but think it could be from an older story or maybe a movie.

At the end of work, an AI is trying to reassure the user that everything will be okay, but end up repeating itself over and over as a punchline. Like:

> Don't worry now. Everything will be ok, will be ok, will be ok... [an so on]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Live-action or animated?

Comment: I think it is some old sci-fie movie that was played in cinema. I though it was A Space Odyssey but I checked and it is not.

Comment: Please edit your question with as much information as you can: when do you think you saw it, did it seem to be an older movie? Where are you? Was the movie in English? Any other details about characters?

Comment: This all that I remember. It seem to be older movie or book. I think it happened in space.

Comment: Did you see it last week? Last month? Last year? Last decade? Last century? And my other prompts?

Comment: We ask for these details so that we can help you (and others) find an answer.

Comment: I read about this ending in last 5 years. So I never saw this movie. That's why I want to identify it.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrokenRecord is the trope, but nothing seems to write match that.

Comment: "Welcome to this automated aircraft...sit back and relax because absolutely nothing can go wrong - can go wrong - go wrong - go wrong..." is a joke that dates back to at least 1961. (In a wide variety of sources, so it's probably from even earlier.)  Saberhagen referenced it in *The Mask of the Sun* (1979), as did John M. Ford in the Alternaties story "Slowly by, Lorena" (1980) and there are certainly far more indirect references in SF literature with variations on the repeated words.

Comment: The television ads for the movie Westworld 1973 had a voice saying "Nothing can go wrong, go wrong, go wrong"

Comment: @DavidW This is it! So it wasn't a movie. Thank you!

Comment: @cyber_fear-which of DavidW's references is the one you were looking for?

Comment: The first one about automated aircraft.

Comment: Poke @DavidW : how about turning that into an answer? :)